# Maintain padding when scaling image inside fixed size container

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to create a zoom effect by using CSS transition to grow an image inside a fixed size container on hover. The container frame has a border and padding, and I would like them to stay when the image grows. The problem is that when it grows, the padding on the right and bottom disappear.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.videoframe {
width: 200px;
height: 113px;
border: solid 2px;
border-radius: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.videoframe img {
border-radius: 20px;
width: 200px;
height: 113px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.videoframe img:hover {
width: 300px;
height: 168px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And here the HTML code:

```
<div class="videoframe"> <img src="image.jpg" /> </div>
```

Is there any way to maintain the 10px padding all the way around the image when it changes size?

Comment: What if you put padding on the img?

Comment: That doesn't work, as the image stretches the padding goes with it, so the right and bottom sides disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've transfered the transition to the frame (when the frame gets hovered, the transition kicks in).

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4R36/3/)

**HTML:** (another div added)

```html
<div class="videoframe">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.ac4bf-thewatch.com/initiates/upload/20130909/big_522e1c989c94f.jpg">
    <div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.videoframe
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 113px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.videoframe div
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.videoframe img
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.videoframe:hover img
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 168px;
}
```

Comment: Same as in Shalom Aptekar's code, here the parent container expands with the image, which I would like to avoid. The parent container needs to remain at the same size whilst the image expands with the overflow being hidden, so we end up seeing only the top left part of the image.

Comment: actually.. he posted his solution after mine.. but never mind. I've updated my solution.

Comment: sorry about that, yes the frame is now staying the same size, but the problem is still there: the padding on the right and bottom disappears when the image grows...

Comment: It works! Adding a second container allows the first to maintain its fixed size, which is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

sorry I'm a little bit confused, do you want the parent container to expand with the image?

if so please see http://jsfiddle.net/NcaAA/

you can use

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box;
```

with

```
padding:10px;
```

to keep consistent padding that takes into account the total width and height you want.

Comment: I would like the parent container to maintain its fixed size, whilst the image inside expands, giving the impression of a video zoom. I think what you suggest would be for an expanding container?

Comment: Oh okay! i would do it this way, it would probably be easier.   http://jsfiddle.net/NcaAA/

Comment: Hmmm unless I'm mistaken, the container still appears to grow with the image.

Comment: sorry forgot to update jsfiddle, my bad. please see :) http://jsfiddle.net/NcaAA/5/

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see any difference, are you sure you've updated it? Does the container remain fixed for you?

Comment: OK I see it now, this is also an excellent working solution which allows the image to grow symmetrically. It just happens that in my case I wanted it to grow out from the top left corner, which is why I accepted the other answer, thanks.