# Make div expand on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, scale, expand

Basically, I just want to create a "relative" scale up of the div i'm hovering. I tried the following, but the output is a disaster. Help would be appericiated!

```
.item
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.item:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 26px;
}
```

Desired solution:

[image]
*IMPORTANT, the problem i'm currently having is keeping the padding between the items on scaling.

Link to: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqkk8zn5/)

Comment: JSFiddle looks good as per given picture!

Comment: @user3135227 It does, but I want the padding to move relatively. So I don't have to give a margin right / margin left.

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833437/maintain-padding-when-scaling-image-inside-fixed-size-container

Comment: @Bilal075 Your question need to be more specific, here on stack overflow, we are not mind readers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expand a div and its contents on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441404/how-to-expand-a-div-and-its-contents-on-hover)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the other two answers is that they only work correctly with a static viewport. Here's a more dynamic solution:

```
.item
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.item:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-right: 6%; /* fallback for ancient browsers that don't support calc() */
    margin-right: calc(5% + 10px);
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqkk8zn5/9/)

Comment: Is it possible to let the padding move relatively, without calculating / setting the margin-right / margin-lefts value?

Comment: This padding _does_ move relatively -- it's 5% of the page width, so it'll be more padding on a wider page. If you adjust the width of the output area in the jsfiddle, you'll see it displays correctly at all widths.

Comment: That's true but i'm still giving the the left / right margin a value. Which is not what I want to do

Comment: I don't understand; why is that a problem? You can't have padding without setting padding.

Comment: Cause whenever i'm setting a padding, the item(s) at the end continues moving, even though they're not affected (the only three items that has to be affected (by the 'hover' effect) has to be the one that's being hovered and the one on its right side and left side.

Comment: Think I might sorta get the idea you're going after, but I can't figure out a way to implement it. Was trying something with having a parent element for each item, but couldn't get it working :P

Comment: Well, found a much cleaner way using transform-origin: 0% 50% and then manually set the margin-right :)

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust your margins, this seems to be working well:

```
.item:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-right: 54px;
    margin-left: 44px;
}
```

Comment: I want the padding to move relatively wise. So without giving the margin-left / margin-right a value.

Comment: You want it to scale vertically but not horizontally? Or do you want the other elements to scale down? Sorry, having trouble understanding that diagram

Comment: I want the effect, it currently has and keep the padding aswell. So whenever i'm hovering an item it scales the item & padding at the same time (without adjusting the margin-left / margin-rights value).

Comment: I see, then could you just adjust width and height instead of scale? Might have to do something fancy to realign them, but you'll keep the padding.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do that with out setting a value.